# A list of functions taking different arguments

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I have a list of functions `list`, with 1-5 elements, each of which is one of the following functions:

```
{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}
```

I also have 2 variables `a, b`. I would like to apply the functions in `list` to these variables, however there is one caveat which is holding me back. `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` take no arguments. `f4` takes `a` as an argument, and `f5` takes `a` and `b` as arguments. I just want to execute all the functions in the list, not store the output in a list or anything, just execute them.

I know how to apply a list of functions to an argument but the fact that some of them take arguments and some don't has stumped me. How can I get this to work?

Comment: So your functions are sth like `f3:=1`, `f4[x_]:=x` and `f5[x_, y_]:=x+y`?

Comment: @corey979 That is correct, however, they have print functions, and don't actually return anything, so I don't want to store the output.

Comment: Usually we ask for a minimum working example to avoid misunderstandings. I suspect there's a better way to do what you need that doesn't involve executing the functions as written...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
ClearAll[tF, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5]
tF = Function[{x, y}, 
      Switch[Head /@ {#[x, y], #@x}, {#, #}, #[], {#, _}, #[x], _, #[x, y]]] &;
```

Example:

```
f1[] := 1; f2[] := 2; f3[] := 3; f4[x_] := x; f5[x_, y_] := x + y; 
flist = {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5};

Through[(tF /@ flist)[x, y]]
(* or *) Operate[tF, #[x, y]] & /@ flist
```

> `{1, 2, 3, x, x + y}`

Or, use `tF` to define an operator:

```
ClearAll[thruF]
thruF[funcs_] := Through[(tF /@ funcs)@##] &;

thruF[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}][x, y]
```

> `{1, 2, 3, x, x + y}`